# Can my saved game in KotOR be used for anything in KotOR 2?

Tags: star-wars-kotor-2

I just finished Knights of the Old Republic and would like to know if I can import the save files in the second game like it can be done in Mass Effect?

I know that Kotor 2  is not made by Bioware.

Also a minor question for the end:

> Is the Star Forge actually drawing power from a star?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second game doesn't follow on directly from the first - most of the characters are different, with some familiar faces and places. So there's little sense in importing a save game, in that respect.

According to [this FAQ](http://www.gamebanshee.com/starwarskotorii/faq.php), there is no way to import a save game from the first game.

**edit** as for your other question:

> The Star Forge was slowly consuming mass and energy from the star, providing the materials for thousands of ships. It also drew upon the darker side of the Force in many ways. more information [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Forge)

Comment: You can "import" how some parts of story went in first game, but not through savegame, but by selecting appropriate answers to Kreia in tutorial zone.

Comment: Much of it is actually from Atton when you first meet him. For instance, he'll talk in vague terms about Revan and then you can answer that Revan was either a man or woman and that he/she saved the galaxy or started a war against it (i.e. the lightside or darkside endings).